# go-runtime doesn't push the object out of the buffered channel

Tags: go, channel

I have a buffered channel of a custom type(user defined structure).  Occasionally I see that the object though pushed into the channel is not being received.

In delve debugger When i print the channel I see 1/100, meaning one object is present in the channel. Also, the go routines which is watching this channel is running(seen in the list of go-routines dumped in delve debugger). Is there a known issue with Go-Runtime ?

Sample code:-

```
func sender() {
    myChan := make(chan mystruct, 10)
    myChan <- mystruct
    app.Debug(appctx.LogTagGen, "Posted mystruct to myChan")
}


func goroutinereceiver() {
for {
    select {
    case mystruct := <-myChan:
        funcx(mystruct)
    }
}
}
```

I can see the message "Posted mystruct to myChan" in the logs. Also, in the delve debugger I can print this channel to see the object present in the channel. Also, i see the receiver goroutine is running:-

> (dlv) print myChan :-
> myChan {mystruct: chan *mystruct **1/100**}

Comment: You cannot debug the runtime with delve. Nothing to see here. No issues.

Comment: @Volker, can you please suggest ways which can used to debug this issue ?

Comment: Also, this is a genuine issue anyone can face. Closing the question is NOT the solution if one doesn't know the answer!

Comment: But closing the question *is* the solution (to the question) if the question doesn't have the right data in it. See [ask].

Comment: It is extremely unlikely that one of the fundamental structures in the Go runtime is broken in this way, and you're the only one encountering it. There is likely something else contributing to the behavior you see, and a [mre] is going to be needed to debug it. If you can reproduce a bug with channels in the runtime, then you should submit that as an issue to the Go team.

Comment: Again, there _is_ no issue. The runtime doesn't have this bug. If channel sends and receives are not working they way you think they should than either your _code_ or your _understanding_ of send/receive are wrong or do not match up.

Comment: The problem is not consistently reproducible. I see the issue one out of ten times. I'm not concluding that there is a issue with go-runtime or with Golang itself. I'm just reaching out to experts to get an idea of how to tackle this issue.

Comment: I see this issue in a complex project of mine. I have only shared the  relevant portion of the code to rule out any obvious logic error. The actual executable itself is comprised of several go routines and several pacakges.

Comment: @Hemanth your question says outright "Is there a known issue with Go-Runtime ?" which certainly makes it seem you think there may be an issue with the Go runtime. Having kept up with Go for some time, I can say with some confidence there is not currently, nor has there been for years, any issue with channel send/receive like this. But to have any hope of diagnosing such an issue, you'd need to provide code to reproduce it, and the Go version, OS, and architecture.

Comment: it needs reproducible example before incriminating the runtime.

Comment: @Adrian,  i agree. Sorry that the questions seems to be blaming the go-routine.  But, i sincerely don't know where to look for the issue. To the best of my understanding go channels selection using the 'Select' construct is handled by go-runtime.

Comment: go version go1.14 linux/amd64. The application runs inside a container of a kubernetes cluster. The host OS for the k8 cluster is Ubuntu 18.04. Docker is the container environment.

Comment: Seeing how the problem is likely in your code, and there is no concept of "pushing" through a channel, the place to start is confirming the status of the channel receivers and checking for basic logical errors. For example, if `routingApp.handleBgpConfigEvent` has any chance of blocking, that loop may never receive another value.

Comment: Based on the code shown, I immediately assume there is an issue with the actual code exhibiting the issue. The construct `for { select { <single case, no default> } }` is pointless, and implies a significant misunderstanding of how Go works. If you can show the relevant code, then the community can likely help identify and resolve the issue.

Comment: @JimB, even if handleBgpConfigEvent is blocking the loop, the I should have received from the channel atleast once, right ? When I print the channel in delve, i see that the channel has one unprocessed object.

Comment: @Adrian, 100% cpu will be consumed only If put a default case inside the select, resulting in a busy checking kinda of logic. Without default, the go routine would be scheduled out of the cpu. Similar to process in sleeping state. Hence, it won't consume 100% cpu. For infosec reasons, I can't share the exact code. The goroutine will be awaken only when go-runtime detects an object available in any of the channels is watching.

Comment: @Hemanth yes, I corrected that immediately. It's still pointless. The whole thing could be replaced by `for bgpCfg = range config.CfgChan.BgpConfigChangeChan`, and would be in well-written code. Which is why this code is highly suspect.

Comment: From the replies, atleast I understand that this is not a logic error or known caveat. @mh-cbon, thanks for the help. But, I can't share the details for obvious reasons. So, no point in wasting my time and others time to look for an answer here. I will go ahead the delete this question.

Comment: Found out the issue:- Whenever the receiving goroutine is executed before the the goroutine which creates the channel. The receiving go routine will go for indefinite sleep when it hits a "nil channel". And that is the issue. Though the channel is created at a later point of time, the receiving goroutine is already in indefinite sleep!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the issue:- Whenever the receiving goroutine is executed before the the goroutine which creates the channel. The receiving go routine will go for indefinite sleep when it hits a "nil channel". And that is the issue. Though the channel is created at a later point of time, the receiving goroutine is already in indefinite sleep! The issue was not consistently seen, as it depends on which goroutine is scheduled first.